# How can I Invalidate a database row while also preserving it for audit purposes?

Tags: database

My database tables holds a number of keys (sensitive information) which are encrypted. These keys are associated with users via an ID field. At any time i may need to invalidate a user by updating their ID field making them no longer identifiable. However i don't want to completely remove the row from the database. Instead i would like to keep it for audit purposes.

Is there a common convention i can follow for this or is simply appending a string with some random content enough to the ID field being invalidated sufficient?

E.g

Table before invalidate request

```
| ID      | KEY        |
------------------------
| user123 | yiuy321ui  |
```

Table after invalidate request

```
| ID                   | KEY        |
--------------------------------------
| legacy_79878_user123 | yiuy321ui  |
```

Comment: is there any reason you can't add another table field to maintain the user status? i think using the ID field to maintain state breaks all convention. if it were me i would just have a simple boolean 'legacy' flag which you could turn on and off.

Comment: yes makes sense, thank you. if you want to add that as answer i can accept for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid using any ID field of any table dynamically. Not only does it defy convention and best practices, but you will likely break associations with other tables which lookup/join on that field. I suggest adding a simple boolean field to your table, and set that field true or false to maintain a users validity.

Answer (score 2):

Updating the user ID is not really a very good way of doing this.  What you want is to be able to say 'this user is not active' anymore, so it would seem to make sense to have an Active bit field on your user table.

You may need to update your code where it validates your user to check for 'active' users only, but this will be easier in the long run (and also make it easier to re-enable a user if you need to).